# Python - How to add an input error message

Tags: python

In Python, I have code where I only want the input to be a number and I want there to be an error message  if the user inputs a string(words). How do I do that?

Comment: Do you want to prompt the user to try again if they give bad input?

Comment: Yes that would be great

Comment: Ok. Kevin's answer in the linked question shows you exactly how to do that. ;)

Comment: It would be great if you append a code stub of what you did for solving your question. With a sample code, your question will be viewed by more users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use try and except

```
userInp = input("YOUR QUESTIONS")
try:
    float(userInp)
except ValueError:
    print("YOUR ERROR")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the input inside a while loop. In the loop you can check the type of the input (make sure to assign it to a variable). Have a condition that exits the loop when the input is a number and give an error message when it is not